# Align 2 payment buttons centered and horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, paypal

I currently have 2 order buttons that work, but align terribly like this:

http://imgur.com/ECRdQai

I need them to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7fdg.png

These are used on my website.

I can get them to align like that by removing the "/form" before bitpay, but it makes it so the bitpay button takes you to the paypal button link. I can only make it take you to the correct order page if I add the "/form" and break the horizontal alignment. Please help.

```
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="200GB/2GB RAM">200GB/2GB RAM</td
</tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<option value="1 MONTH">1 MONTH $25.00 USD</option>
<option value="3 MONTHS">3 MONTHS $65.00 USD</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ORLogUb.png" border="0" name="submit"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/ORLogUb.png" width="1" height="1">
</form>
<form action="https://bitpay.com/checkout" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="cartAdd" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/pSatyZL.png" border="1" name="submit"
alt="BitPay, pay with bitcoins." >
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, and my website is basically vanilla CSS and a bunch of HTML. WORKING METHOD: http://jsfiddle.net/kJ8LM/

Comment: This is the non working method with the alignment I want: http://jsfiddle.net/HdPm4/1/ Thanks so much for any help! Just to clarify, by non-working I mean that it looks fine, but clicking the 2nd button brings you to the url of the 1st button (paypal checkout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See live example on http://jsfiddle.net/fuSYL/

You need additional div wrapper for those two forms and also some css.

HTML

```
<div class="form-container"> 

<!-- from paypal -->
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="200GB/2GB RAM">200GB/2GB RAM
    </p>
    <p>    
        <select name="os0">
            <option value="1 MONTH">1 MONTH $25.00 USD</option>
            <option value="3 MONTHS">3 MONTHS $65.00 USD</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/ORLogUb.png" border="0" name="submit"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" class="button-paypal">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/ORLogUb.png" width="1" height="1">
</form>
<!-- /from paypal -->

<!-- form bitpay -->    
<form action="https://bitpay.com/checkout" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cartAdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/pSatyZL.png" name="submit"
alt="BitPay, pay with bitcoins." class="button-bitpay">
</form>
<!-- /form bitpay -->

</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-container {   
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}

.form-container p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    padding: 0;
}

.button-paypal {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -90px;
}

.button-bitpay {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Great. Am I able to copy the HTML form for as many buttons as I need? Or will these conflict? The CSS information can just be added to my styles.css correct? Im trying to slowly clean my website code as I gain more knowledge, thanks for contributing to that!

Comment: Ive edited a button using the fix above, but now the bottons are showing at absolute bottom centered with the page, basically in the footer.

Comment: Don't forget about position:relative for div around those forms. Buttons would be visible at footer if you don't apply position:relative property to the parent div.

Comment: OK adding the <div class="paypal-button"> and <div class="bitpay-button"> ? I'm also not completely sure im adding the css to the correct location in my styles file. Is there a more complete jsfiddle I can provide?

Comment: Edited post. See <div class="form-container"> at top. You need this div also.

Comment: Not sure what my problem is now, the jsfiddle with the corrections looks perfect, but the buttons are strange on the live site. you can check it here. I'm not sure why as the jsfiddle has the entirety of the html and css code. http://jsfiddle.net/Lx6cs/ and http://stonabox.me/

Comment: It's the same for me, I mean don't see differences on live site and on your JSFiddle. Try clear the browser cache, maybe you load old css. Also you can debug css with Firebug or Chrome DevTools, because there maybe conflict with other css styles on live site.

Comment: Ive cleared the browser cache, and im grabbing firebug now. Heres an image of the current "view" im having. http://i.imgur.com/z0GdpgS.png

Comment: Well, I see. For `.from-container` change css to `padding: 0px 0px 16px;` ... `.button-paypal` -> `margin: 0 0 0 -78px;` ... `.button-bitpay` -> `margin: 0 0 0 4px;`

Comment: You my friend, are awesome. Ive struggled with this issue for a week, and you just solved it, Thank you kindly!